# Knockout Observable Array increasing memory after updates

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-mvc

I am having a memory issue when updating a observable array in knockout.  Each time, I run my update script, the memory seems to increase like so 
[image]

I feel like I might be updating the wrong way.  I have to grab info from the server every minute to keep the list up to date. I am doing so like:

```
 var Update = function () {
 setTimeout(function () {
     ko.mapping.fromJS(data.Students, vm.students)
     Update();
 }, 5000)}
```

But, like I said, the memory increases every time I grab info and then it eventually crashes the site.  The array I am working with is about 110-120 objects.  Here is a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71bs45es/3/) showing a small example of what I am doing.  I have read that with larger data sets it might be a better idea to stray away from the mapping plugin, is this something I should do? Seems to still happen with small data sets too.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is Update being called externally as well? Anyway, look at the *retained size* of the vm after each Update call..

Comment: Yes, Update gets called right after binding, but that is just to start the timeout process to run every minute.

Comment: How would I look at the retained size after each update?

Comment: In Chrome under the Memory Snapshot you can look up by type of object (by constructor). This will show the retained size and number of such objects - which is memory the GC is not allowed to release because it is reachable. It should be possible to use this to tell if the issue is caused *by* the vm object-graph growing each time.

Comment: It looks like the retained size of vm stays about the same after each update.  So if it is not the array, what would be causing this increase?

Comment: I have no idea, but let's see: 1) Does this increased memory ever cause the browser to use too-much memory or is it "eventually" capped? Running with a much smaller interval might show a limiting behavior. 2) Does there persist some HTML that maintains a binding to some old observable that has been "replaced" in the VM? (Along with this: which object(s) in the Memory Profile keep having more instances created? The Memory Allocation profile can also be used, which allows "timeslicing".)

Comment: The site gets to the point where it stops responding and Chrome will give that pop up to kill it. Usually this is after about 20 or so minutes of running.  How would HTML maintain a binding like that? In the Jsfiddle, is basically how my html is for the actual site

Answer (score 1):

By having Update() call itself you may be holding onto some scope.  Any reason you're not using setInterval?

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data.Students, vm.students)
    }, 5000)}
// eventually, when you're done
clearInterval(interval)
```